# In Unmanaged C++ Dll call From Managed C# Application, How to handle conflicts between Datatypes

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, dllimport

**How to handle datatype conflicts?**
For Example.
in C# there is a data type called String which is absent in C.

**How to return multiple values from  C or C++ to C# after the call.**

**If I use user defined data types how to handle that in both the languages without conflicts?**

Comment: In which version of `C` is an `int` 2 bytes in length?  And since when was an `int` 8 bytes in C#???  Both of them currently define an `int` as 4 bytes, as far as I can tell.  There's a `short` in both that are 2 bytes, and a long in both that is 8 bytes.

Comment: At least help me with 2nd and 3rd question If you feel my first question is lame. @Corey

Comment: 2: Return a struct.  3: Use the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace attributes `StructLayout` and `FieldOffset` to handle different structure layouts, and `MarshalAs` to manage simple type conversions (mostly for strings).  Lots of example code out there - google for 'c# unmanaged struct' for starters.

Comment: Thanks Corey   @Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog should solve all your doubts and concerns
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/borisj/archive/2006/09/28/769708.aspx